# Returning 2D char array from C function to java JNI

Tags: java, c, arrays

I am trying to display a 5x5 grid of characters from a 2D char array from a C function, in java. The code I am using at the moment returns a correct 5x5 grid, however all the characters within the grid are displayed as either null or random symbols. The code I am using to construct are return the array is the following:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_MapJNI_look(JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject, jint x, jint y){

initializeMap();

jobjectArray lookRow[5];
char lookChars[5][5];
char *arrayPointer;

int i, j, k, l;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){

        int posX = x + j - 5/2;
        int posY = y + i - 5/2;

        if(posX >= 0 && posX < getMapWidth() && posY >= 0 && posY < getMapHeight()){
            lookChars[i][j] = map[posY][posX]; //todo check this is correct
        }else{
            lookChars[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
    arrayPointer = &lookChars[i][j];

    //Setting an element of the row array object to a particular sequence of map characters
    //5 represents the 5x5 look window
    lookRow[i] = createArrayRow(env, 5, arrayPointer);
}
//Creating an array that contains all the rows for the look window
//Any element of lookRow[] is valid when obtaining the class through GetObjectClass
jobjectArray rows = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 5, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, lookRow[0]), 0);

for(k = 0; k < 5; k++){
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,rows,k, lookRow[k]);
}

return rows; }
```

The initializeMap() function simply fills the 2D char array with '.' characters. The createArrayRow() function is below:

```
static jobjectArray createArrayRow(JNIEnv *env, jsize count, char* elements){

  //Storing the class type for the object passed
  jclass stringClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
  //Creating a jobjectArray out of the supplied information
  //This creates an array that can be passed back to java
  jobjectArray row = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, stringClass, 0);
  jsize i;

  //Assigning each element of the newly created array object to a specific   string
  (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, row, i, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, elements));

return row; }
```

If you have any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In C, if `rows` is an array as the comment says, `return rows;` only returns a pointer, not an array, to an now invalid object.  A complete, minimal code sample to replicate the problem here is advised,

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have adopted creates an array of characters and then merges each array together to create a 2D jobjectArray of character arrays. Each row of the object array is an array of characters.

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_MyClass_get2DArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject){

jchar singleArrayRow[10]; //Change 10 to the width of the 2D array
jcharArray arrayRows[10]; //Change 10 to the height of the 2D array

//Looping through the array and adding the relevant characters to an array 
int i, j, k, l;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        //Using another array in order to passes the row of characters to createArrayRow function
        singleArrayRow[j] = arrayOfChars[i][j]; //arrayOfChars is just the previously specified char **arrayOfChars  
    }
    arrayRows[i] = createArrayRow(env, 10, singleArrayRow);
}
//Creating the object
jobjectArray rows = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 10, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, arrayRows[0]), 0); //You can use any element of arrayRows[]

//Looping through the jobjectArray and aligning it each row object
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, rows, i, arrayRows[i]);
}
return rows}
```

The createArrayRow(JNIEnv *env, int length, jchar rowChar[]) function accepts the java working environment, followed by the array length and the actual array of characters that you want to convert into jobjectArray

```
static jcharArray createArrayRow(JNIEnv *env, int length, jchar rowChar[]){

//Creating an array of type jcharArray
jcharArray rowOfChars = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, length);

//Setting the region for the array
(*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, rowOfChars, 0, length, rowChar);

return rowOfChars;}
```

The last for loop in the get2DArray() function sets each element of the newly created jobjectArray, rows, with each jobjectArray created via the createArrayRow() function. Strictly speaking, the get2DArray() function returns a pointer to a jobjectArray, but java unwraps that pointer for you.